# Merged two or more IEnumerable<string> to add a dropdownlist in (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

```
    IEnumerable<string> names1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\folder\\", "*.pdf").Select(fullName => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullName));
    IEnumerable<string> names2= Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\folder\\", "*.pdf").Select(fullName => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullName));
    IEnumerable<string> merge==??
```

In Page_Load:

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlChoose.DataSource = merge;
            ddlChoose.DataBind();
        }
```

What should I write "??" instead? Or do you have any other suggestions for what I want to do?

Comment: You can also checkout AddRange() method on list.
Here is the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can merge 2 enumerables by using concat.

```
IEnumerable<string> s1 = new List<string>(new[] { "A", "B", "C" });
IEnumerable<string> s2 = new List<string>(new[] { "D", "E", "F" });
IEnumerable<string> s3 = s1.Concat(s2);
```

if you need single results you could use Union

```
IEnumerable<string> s1 = new List<string>(new[] { "A", "B", "C" });
IEnumerable<string> s2 = new List<string>(new[] { "D", "E", "F" });
IEnumerable<string> s3 = new List<string>(new[] { "A", "E", "G" });

IEnumerable<string> s4 = s1.Union(s2).Union(s3);
```

Comment: error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Anasayfa.names1'

Comment: This might be unrelated. At what point do you get this error?

Comment: It didn't happen because I wrote it(...concat..) under my global codes. I wrote to the local and it happened. Thank you.